# Strange behaviour when inserting tabs

Tags: indentation

I thought I knew how Vim handles indentation but apparently I was wrong.
When I type  at the beginning of a line, everything seems to work as expected. However when I type  somewhere inside a line, strange things happen.

Suppose my options are set as follows:

```
set filetype=c
set cindent
set tabstop=8
set shiftwidth=8
set softtabstop=0
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬,space:-
```

That being said I would expect every `▸` tab character to have equivalent length of `tabstop=8`. That is not the case. What happens is this:
[image]

How can I configure Vim to show every tab character with equivalent length?

Answer (score 2):

Tab characters *don't* have fixed width; that's the purpose.

The original purpose of tabulation is to create neat columns. It's magic: you press one button, and the cursor is automatically at the beginning of the next column. What you define with `tabstop` is, in reality, the width of those columns; it *isn't* the width of the tab character.

If you really need equivalent spacing, just add the number of spaces you want. Vim's `i`, `a`, `o` etc. accept counts, so you can just do `8i <Esc>` (in Normal mode) to add 8 spaces at current position.